# Does the Boltzmann equation reduce to Navier-Stokes equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes, boltzmann-equation

Since the derivation of the Boltzmann Equation uses the molecular chaos assumption, it seems to me that it should not be valid for dense systems such as fluids. Now, according to Chapman-Enskog theory, the Boltzmann equation can be represented by a series expansion in powers of the Knudsen Number. If we take the first two terms in this series, we get the Navier-Stokes equation. But, the Navier-Stokes equation is valid for the motion of viscous fluid substances which disobey the molecular chaos assumption.

This sounds to me like a contradiction. How could the Boltzmann equation reduce to the Navier-Stokes equation even though it uses the molecular chaos assumption?

Comment: Molecular chaos at macroscopic level can be described with density,  velocity, temperature and equation of state. The system of Navier-Stokes equations for compressible viscous gas includes equations for density, velocity, temperature and equation of state as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176776/2451

Comment: @RoshanTom See my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @RogerVadim. Thank you for pointing me to that.