# Introductory text to the Boltzmann equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, boltzmann-equation

I'm searching for a good introductory text to the [Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation) and how it gets applied in the relativistic case as well?

Comment: Perhaps the last two links in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/682577/247642) will help (I can't recommend anything specific on relativistic case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many introductions to kinetic theory and the Boltzmann equation. I tend to think that you can't go wrong with [volume X of Landau and Lifshitz](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physical_Kinetics/DTHxPDfV0fQC?hl=en&gbpv=0), but Landau is very brief on the relativistic case.

A nice general introduction that covers the relativistic (and, to some extent, the quantum) case is [Richard Liboff, Kinetic Theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kinetic_Theory/9_LfoChz3GcC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

There are specialized books on the relativistic theory too. An old one is [John Stewart, Non-Equilibrium
Relativistic Kinetic Theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Non_equilibrium_Relativistic_Kinetic_The/UJhYAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (mostly about the basics), or [De Groot et al., Relativistic Kinetic Theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Relativistic_Kinetic_Theory/wkZ-AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (includes applications to mixtures of various elementary particles). [Cercignani and Kremer, The Relativistic Boltzmann Equation: Theory and Applications](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Relativistic_Boltzmann_Equation_Theo/5X8ECAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) also covers the general relativistic case. A more recent book is [Vereshchagin and Aksenov, Relativistic Kinetic Theory](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Relativistic_Kinetic_Theory/pjQEDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), which has some applications to astrophysical plasmas.

Many books describe applications of relativistic kinetic theory to problems in cosmology, astrophysical fluid dynamics, and relativistic heavy ion collisions, for example [Weinberg's book on cosmology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cosmology/rswTDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), or [Rezolla's book on relativistic fluid dynamics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Relativistic_Hydrodynamics/aS1oAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).